# es6 import 'destructuring' not working

Tags: ecmascript-6

Hey there I have this uiTypes.js file like this:

```
export default {
  SELECT_ITEM: 'SELECT_ITEM',
  DESELECT_ITEM: 'DESELECT_ITEM',
  TOGGLE_ITEM: 'TOGGLE_ITEM',
}
```

And when I try importing its content like so, it works:

```
import uiTypes from './uiTypes';
console.log(uiTypes.SELECT_ITEM) // 'SELECT_ITEM'
```

But not like this:

```
import { SELECT_ITEM, DESELECT_ITEM, TOGGLE_ITEM } from './uiTypes';
console.log(SELECT_ITEM) // undefined,
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no destructuring for imports (notice also that exports and imports use the keyword `as` instead of a colon to avoid confusion with objects). You can either import the default export, individual named exports, or the module namespace object.

Your attempt is trying to import three named exports, while there is only a default export; that's why it's failing.

You should use named exports:

```
export const SELECT_ITEM = 'SELECT_ITEM';
export const DESELECT_ITEM = 'DESELECT_ITEM';
export const TOGGLE_ITEM = 'TOGGLE_ITEM';
```

or use "real" destructuring after importing the object:

```
import uiTypes from './uiTypes';
const {SELECT_ITEM, DESELECT_ITEM, TOGGLE_ITEM} = uiTypes;
```

Comment: I see! Yeah I am doing the destructuring post-import. I like the remark on the "as" is used as opposed to colon, that's a nice mental hook to lean on. Thanks!